# Error in view file

Tags: zend-framework, netbeans

I'm new to zend framework.I'm getting the following error when trying to view the page

```
Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in D:\xampp\htdocs\neemjobs\application\views\scripts\register\index.phtml on line 1

class RegisterController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{

    public function init()
    {
        /* Initialize action controller here */
    }

    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->view->pageTitle = "Zend_Form Example";
        $this->view->bodyCopy = "<p >Please fill out this form.</p>";

        $form = new forms_ContactForm();
        $this->view->form = $form;

    }


}
```

My View is

```
<?php echo $this->pageTitle ;?>
<?php echo $this->bodyCopy ;?>
```

Comment: Is that your complete view? Try doing a var_dump at the top of your view file

Answer (score 1):

This is totally correct (on my Zend Framework installation goes perfectly, I just don't understand "in which way" are you using the Form... but, anyway, it works, so the "bug" is not there...